# Form is submitting only the final row data in a foreach loop, not the correct selection information

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, foreach

I had originally had the form inside of the foreach(ran into issues that seemed unsolvable because it would call the function as many times as the foreach had listed).

So now, with the `<form>` outside of the foreach it will only submit the data from the final collection in the foreach loop. But what I **need it to do is send the data depending on which item in the foreach loop is checked.**

This is my function for submitting the information to the database:

```
function user_add_new() {
    global $wpdb;
    $bookTOadd = $_POST["book"];
    $listTOadd = $_POST["listID"];
    $userID = $_POST["user"];

    $addTABLE = $wpdb->prefix . 'plugin_read';
    
    $wpdb->insert( 
        $addTABLE, 
        array( 
            'bookID' => $bookTOadd, 
            'userID' => $userID, 
            'listID' => $listTOadd, 
        ) 
    );
}
```

And this is my foreach loop with the form outside of it:

```
<form action="<?php user_add_new();?>" method="post">
     <?php 
     foreach($books_array as $i ) {
            $s = $i->title;
            $o = $i->listID;
            $r = $i->submittedBy;
            $d = $i->bookDESC;
            $t = $i->id;
            $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
            $current_id = $current_user->ID;
            ?>
            <?php if($r == ''.$current_user->ID.''|| $r == 'administrator') { ?>
            <div class="user-wrap">
                <div class="inner-wrap">
            <!---entire checkbox--->
                    <div><span class="check">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="" onChange="this.form.submit()">
                        <input type="hidden" name="item" value="<?php echo $t;?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="listID" value="<?php echo $o;?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="userID" value="<?php echo $current_id;?>">
                    </span></div>
            <!---entire checkbox--->
            <!---info from book--->
                    <div>
                        <b><?php echo $s; ?></b><br>
                        <?php echo $d; ?>
                    </div>
            <!---info from book--->
                </div>
            </div>
    
            
            <?php } else {
            }; ?>
    <?php
         
     };
    ?>
</form>
```

I did check the output with `var_export($_POST);` and it indeed does only return the data for the final item in the foreach loop when it needs to **return data depending on which foreach item is checked**

I have been stuck on this single form for hours now, I think I need a fresh mind to help find the solution. I truly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as your form:

```
<form action="<?php user_add_new();?>" method="post">
<?php
foreach($books_array as $index => $i ) {
    $s = $i->title;
    $o = $i->listID;
    $r = $i->submittedBy;
    $d = $i->bookDESC;
    $t = $i->id;
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $current_id = $current_user->ID;

    if ($r == $current_user->ID || $r == 'administrator') {
        echo '<div class="user-wrap">';
            echo '<div class="inner-wrap">';
                echo '<!---entire checkbox--->';
                echo '<div><span class="check">';
                    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='$index' onChange='this.form.submit()'>";
                    echo "<input type='hidden' name='item$index' value='$t'>";
                    echo "<input type='hidden' name='listID$index' value='$o'>";
                    echo "<input type='hidden' name='userID$index' value='$current_id'>";
                echo '</span></div>';
                echo '<!---entire checkbox--->';
                echo '<!---info from book--->';
                echo "<div><b>$s</b><br>$d</div>";
                echo "<!---info from book--->";
            echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
};
?>
</form>
```

I've removed the many `<?php ?>` statements and echoed the HTML in PHP. Also notice checkbox input has `name='checkbox[]' value = '$index'`.

The `[]` after the name means the values of the checked checkboxes will come through as an array in `$_POST["checkbox"]`. Since you are immediately submitting the form as soon as one is checked, you should only have one value in this array so we access that in the `user_add_new()` function with `$_POST["checkbox"][0]`

Then this is the function:

```
function user_add_new() {
    global $wpdb;

    $value = $_POST["checkbox"][0];
    $bookTOadd = $_POST["item" . $value];
    $listTOadd = $_POST["listID" . $value];
    $userID = $_POST["userID" . $value];

    $addTABLE = $wpdb->prefix . 'plugin_read';

    $wpdb->insert(
        $addTABLE,
        array(
            'bookID' => $bookTOadd,
            'userID' => $userID,
            'listID' => $listTOadd,
        )
    );
}
```

You had `$bookTOadd = $_POST["book"];` but I couldn't see an input with book as a name so I assume this should be item?

Comment: Would that work well in wordpress though, if I do a file, won't it try to go to that file (as a page) and then not work? (at the moment with the function I am using, it is sending the data to the database -- just the wrong data)

Comment: Also is it possible to give an example using the isset($_POST) of the function I am trying to accomplish? I can give it a try then and see if it sends the correct data and not just the final foreach data. Thank you for taking the time to answer!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't use WordPress so can't answer if the file will be treated as a page, but in terms of PHP, you can absolutely put a path to a file as the form action and it will execute it.

Comment: I'm willing to give it a try, can you update your answer with what should go in the php file (using the isset, I don't quite understand using isset yet in my php learning journey)? And I'll let you know after trying it if it sends the last item in the foreach loop or the correct one (I am really hoping the correct one, having a solution would be great, I truly appreciate your time!). Thank you!

Comment: I gave it a try and in the php file it did not work. But I did add the code where I regularly had it, even with using isset it still sends the last item in the foreach loop and not the actual item clicked. The issue I think is the form is not picking up on the data of the item checked, it's only pulling the data from the final data set in the foreach loop. With that in mind, do you know of a way in PHP to get that to work? Thank you again!

Comment: Maybe a way of making the names for the inputs unique(no idea how that would work)? Do you think that could fix it?

Comment: Yes, the issue is that you have multiple inputs with the same name e.g. 'listID' and they are overwriting each other in the $_POST array. I will amend my answer to try and fix this but it is difficult not being able to debug it.

Comment: I have tried the code provided and it's not sending anything to the database, this is what I get when I click a checkbox for item with the id of 5 `array ( ‘item0’ => ‘4’, ‘listID0’ => ‘1’, ‘userID0’ => ‘2’, ‘checkbox’ => array ( 0 => ‘1’, ), ‘item1’ => ‘5’, ‘listID1’ => ‘1’, ‘userID1’ => ‘2’, ‘item4’ => ‘9’, ‘listID4’ => ‘1’, ‘userID4’ => ‘2’, ‘item5′ => ’10’, ‘listID5’ => ‘6’, ‘userID5’ => ‘2’, )` It's putting all that is in the foreach into an array when the checkbox is clicked. It really is difficult. I have no idea where I've gone wrong >.<

Comment: I've even tried the form inside of the foreach, and it does send the correct one but the only issue is that it sends it however many times the items is in the foreach. So I thought outside of the foreach would be easier to debug, but it looks like it might be just as difficult >.<

Comment: The array looks as I would expect. The value of the first (and only) entry in the checkbox array is '1'. So we need to load values for 'item1', listID1' and 'userID1' which should be '5', '1' and '2'. If you echo `$bookTOadd`, `$listTOadd`, and `$userID` in the function do the values look correct?

Comment: It's showing 51, the item its having trouble sending then must be the userID, it should be 2

Comment: Sorry. In my answer `$userID = $_POST["user" . $value];` should be `$userID = $_POST["userID" . $value];`. I will edit.

Comment: YOU ARE AMAZING! THANK YOU SO MUCH! I swear I sat there looking at the form and the functions and for some reason the name userID and the function up there did not register. Thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: I hate to ask one more question but would you happen to know how to refresh the entire page after a form is submitted? I have it refreshing after form submission but it only reloads other areas and not the list area (where the checkboxes are). If not that is absolutely okay! You've been the biggest help, thank you! A true learning experience

Comment: No problem, happy to help :-). Regarding reloading you could try changing your javascript that submits the form from `this.form.submit()` to `this.form.submit(); location.reload();`

Comment: That made it submit every time the page reloaded and I ended up with a lot of duplicates, thank you so much for the help though it really means a lot!